# Rails: Error while executing rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I don't know but for some reason my rake db:migrate command is getting aborted. When I run:

```
 rake db:migrate >> logfile
```

and then

```
 less logfile
```

I get:

```
==  FixProductsTable: migrating ===============================================
-- rename_column(:products, :meata_description, :meta_description)
[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
==  CreateCkeditorAssets: migrating ===========================================
-- create_table(:ckeditor_assets)
[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
==  FixProductsTable: migrating ===============================================
-- rename_column(:products, :meata_description, :meta_description)
[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
==  RenameColumnHeathFactorToHealthFactorOnProducts: migrating ================
==  RenameColumnHeathFactorToHealthFactorOnProducts: migrated (0.0000s) =======

==  AddColumnCityToProducts: migrating ========================================
-- add_column(:products, :city, :string)
[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass    SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
==  CreatePhotos: migrating ===================================================
-- create_table(:photos)
```

I tried deleting Photos table, wrote drop_table in photos migration, but nothing happening. I keep getting above output in my logfile. It is as if deleting photos table/migration is not affecting rake db:migrate.

But logfile shows migration is aborted at creating photos.

I am not getting how to solve this. Can someone help?

P.S. I am not able to login via ssh. It is closed due to some reason. So I am on lish login of linode and hence looking in logfile for error.

Comment: First of all add a full log. I bet there's something  after `-- create_table(:photos)`

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Unfortunately I am not able to get full log. Is there any way to see full log? It will be great help. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by unable? Can't you just stop putting log in file (`>>`) and write it to the screen?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel u mean this way: rake db:migrate logfile? Ran it but same output as I wrote in question.

Comment: Do you understand what `>>` operator does in bash? It redirects output from command to file (appends to be exact). Just run `rake db:migrate` with nothing else added and paste COMPLETE log

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Oh. Sorry for that. Didnt know that. Actually I am not able to scroll up in my terminal to see log from the start as I am logged in with lish in linode cause my ssh is closed. Hence taking output in logfile.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36635/discussion-between-user2206724-and-michael-szyndel)

Comment: Yes, so probably exception was writhed to stderr, which will be console output, not file. Look for it, it must me somewhere there